# selector.trigger("click") is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

In my html, when I click on "Continue" button , an overlay appears. That overlay has "Skip and Continue" button.
When I click on "Skip and Continue" button an another overlay appears replacing the first one.
My expectation is : When I click the "Continue" button, the action of "Skip and Continue" button should trigger and second overlay should appear and first overlay should never appear.
I have written below piece of code to perform the action of "Skip and Continue" button on the click of "Continue" button and hide the first overlay but this is not working.

```
<script>

function overlayBannerLoad()
{
  var delayAdd = setInterval(function() 
         {
         $(".yelbtn").click(function(event)
            { 
                console.log("Conitnue button is clicked");
                event.preventDefault(); 

                if($('.flexi-promotion-popup').children('.ReactModal__Overlay.ReactModal__Overlay').length > -1)                    
                {
                    console.log("first overlay found");
                    $('.btn.btn-indigo.skip-cnt-btn').trigger("click");
                    console.log("skip and conitnue button is clicked");
                    $('.ReactModal__Content.ReactModal__Content').remove();
                    console.log("first overlay is removed");
                        clearInterval(delayAdd);
                } 
                else
                {
                clearInterval(delayAdd);
                }
            }); 
        }, 100);
  }
 window.onclick = function(){overlayBannerLoad();};
  window.onload = function(){overlayBannerLoad();};
</script>
```

HTML:

CONTINUE BUTTON :

```
<button id="continue-button" class="yelbtn">
    <span><!-- react-text: 40 -->Continue<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 41 --> <!-- /react-text -->
        <i class="fa icon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</button>
```

DIV WHEN CONTINUE BUTTON IS NOT CLICKED YET

```
<div class="flexi-promotion-popup">
    <div data-reactroot="">
    </div>
</div>
```

DIV WHEN CONTINUE BUTTON HAS BEEN CLICKED

```
<div class="flexi-promotion-popup">
    <div data-reactroot="" class="ReactModal__Overlay ReactModal__Overlay--after-open popup-overlay-desktop black upgrade-popup">
        <div class="ReactModal__Content ReactModal__Content--after-open popup-container-desktop modal-dialog upgrade-popup-ie" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Flexi-Promotion-Popup">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 id="myModalLabel">
                        <span class="f22">Add flexibility to your travel</span> 
                        <button type="button" class="closeBtn pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <i class="icon-close-stroke"></i>
                        </button>
                    </h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body text-left">
                     <div class="title">
                         <span><!-- react-text: 12 -->BLR<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 13 --> <!-- /react-text --></span>
                             <i class="icon-flight-right"></i>
                         <span><!-- react-text: 16 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 17 -->IXC<!-- /react-text --></span>
                         <span><!-- react-text: 19 --> &nbsp;(<!-- /react-text -->
                             <span>Saver Fare</span><!-- react-text: 21 -->)<!-- /react-text -->
                         </span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media">
                          <div class="media-left">
                              <div class="pp-img text-center">
                                  <img src="/etc/designs/abc-reservation/clientlibs-react/images/popups/unlimited-changes.png" alt="">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media-body bg-flight text-left">
                          <div class="jumbo-text">
                              <span>Make unlimited changes to your booking at additional
                              </span>
                              <span><!-- react-text: 30 -->&nbsp;<!-- /react-text -->
                                  <span>₹&nbsp;354</span><!-- react-text: 32 -->*<!-- /react-text -->
                              </span>
                              <div>
                                  <button class="btn btn-abc"><!-- react-text: 35 -->Add to trip<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 36 --> <!-- /react-text -->
                                      <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
                                  </button>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-abc skip-cnt-btn ml20" data-dismiss="modal"><!-- react-text: 39 -->Skip and continue <!-- /react-text -->
                                      <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
                                   </button>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <span>
                       <p>*Fare difference applies. For more details,&nbsp;
                           <a href="https://www.goabc.in/information/new-fare-types.html" target="_blank" adhocenable="false">Click here.</a>
                       </p>
                   </span>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please also show your HTML, as it's difficult to figure out what your issue is

Comment: Try these cahnges:
$(".yelbtn").click(function(event) > $(document).on('click', function(event)

Comment: Hi @ChrisSatchell I have added the html now.

Comment: Hi @MikeAron I have tried the on('click', function (event)) but that was not working

Comment: Please learn how to format your HTML part, it wasn't even readable, can you read that 50+ lines of Html which is shown in 3 lines only?

Comment: Hi @ChrisSatchell I have provided the banner, can you please check it now?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Everyone, I have writtent below code :

$('button.yelbtn').click(function()
   {    
    $('button.btn.btn-indigo.skip-cnt-btn').trigger('click');
    $('.flexi-promotion-popup').hide();
   });

This script is not displaying the first overlay banner on the click of Continue button. However when I re-click the Continue button then second overlay is appearing. Now I want to display the second overlay on the first click of Continue button.

Comment: @AmbikaTewari Do you want both buttons to do the same thing? I'm confused

Comment: Why are you even using `setInterval`?

Comment: Hi @ChrisSatchell I am able to resolve this partially.I have modified below javascript code so that When I re-click the Continue button than "Skip and Continue" button action happens. I want Skip and continue button action to trigger on the single click of Continue button

$('button.yelbtn').click(function()
            {    
                $('button.btn.btn-indigo.skip-cnt-btn').trigger('click');
                $('.flexi-promotion-popup').hide();
            });

Comment: Add all the logic to the `Skip & Continue` button and just trigger a click on that button when you click `Continue`. Most of the code needed for that to work has already been written by you.

Comment: Raised https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51474240/triggger-action-of-second-click-on-first-click-only for new issue.